# R 3.0.1 (yes its old) fails to define R_CStackDir

Tags: r, build, rjava

Building R 3.0.1 from source for an integration that requires this particular version (via rJava) defines some other R_CStack* stuff but only seems to define R_CStackDir (src/gnuwin32/system.c) inside of a function void R_SetWin32(Rstart Rp) ... R_CStackDir = 1;

Supposedly the default is -1 and I take it from the function name that Windows behaves differently from Linux (Redhat 7) which would use the default -1... except I don't find that anywhere.

When rJava (0.8 and 0.9) compiles and tries to load I get an undefined symbol for R_CStackDir.

Has anyone seen this on RHEL and solved it?

R built and was installed, and it configured Java with no obvious error.

```
sudo R CMD javareconf \
→ JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME} \
→ JAVA=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java \
→ JAVAC=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javac \
→ JAVAH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javah \
→ JAR=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jar \
→ JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/lib64/R/lib/ \
→ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/lib64/R/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} \
→ JAVA_LIBS="$JAVA_LIBS -ldl" \
→ R_HOME=/usr/local/lib64/R \
→ JAVA_CPPFLAGS="-I${JAVA_HOME}/include -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux"

/usr/local/lib64/R/bin/javareconf: line 66: -ldl: command not found
/usr/local/lib64/R/bin/javareconf: line 66: -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64/include/linux: No such file or directory
Java interpreter : /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_232
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64
Java compiler    : /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI progam 
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/local/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64/include/linux -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -L/usr/local/lib64/R/lib -lR


Java library path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/local/lib64/R/lib/
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /usr/local/lib64/R
Done.
```

Comment: I see that building R from source defines R_CStackDir in a header file dependent on __MAIN__ ... so the question seems to be how to get it define in the build?

Comment: I can get the symbol defined but its still not working.....

Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  rJava.so: undefined symbol: R_CStackDir

(/usr/local/src/rJava)$ nm ./src/rJava.so | grep R_CStackDir
U R_CStackDir
(/usr/local/src/rJava)$ nm /usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.so | grep R_CStackDir
00000000004795cc d R_CStackDir